# Re-render templates on route change in Meteor 1.3

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I'm using Flow Router and Blaze Renderer for a simple website (think blog / brochureware).

I'm using `FlowRouter.path()` to create links on my menu elements. The url changes as expected when these links are clicked and the `action(`) method on the route is fired. However the templates don't seem to be refreshed and the template helpers aren't fired.

The route in my /lib/route.js file is

```
const about = FlowRouter.group({
  prefix: '/about'
});

about.route('/:pageSlug/:subSectionSlug', {
  action: (params) => {
    console.log('action() fired :' + params.pageSlug + ' :' + params.subSectionSlug);
    BlazeLayout.render( 'applicationLayout', {
      main: 'basicPage',
    });
  },
  name: 'pageSubsection',
});
```

Then my templates looks like -

```
<template name="applicationLayout">
        {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
</template>

<template name="basicPage">
    <div id="pageWrapper">
        ...
        <aside class="leftBar subSectionMenu">
            {{> sidebar }}
        </aside>
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<template name="sidebar">
    <ul class="pageMenu">
        {{#each subSections }}
            {{> sidebarItem}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="sidebarItem">
    <a class="sidebarItemAnchor" href="{{ href }}">
        <li class="sidebarItem .hoverItem {{#if isSelected }} selected {{/if}}">
            {{title}}
            <span class="sidebarArrow"></span>
        </li>
    </a>
</template>
```

With a simple helper to add the `selected` class to the `li` element -

```
Template.sidebarItem.helpers({
  href() {
    const subSection = this;
    const params = {
      pageSlug: subSection.pageSlug,
      subSectionSlug: subSection.slug,
    }
    return FlowRouter.path('pageSubsection', params, {});
  },
  isSelected() {
    const slug = FlowRouter.current().params.subSectionSlug;
    console.log('running isSelected with ' + slug);
    if (this.slug === slug) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

I think I must be misunderstanding how (and when) templates are rendered.

What do I need to do to re-render these templates when the route changes?

Comment: Hi. Do you have any solution for it? I want it behave like a normal route change without reloading the complete page. Other recommendations were using BlazeLayout.reset() which basically does a re-render, but it feels really ugly&bad

Answer (score 0):

Flow Router was designed to work like this. It doesn't automatically re-render.

A simple fix is to add `FlowRouter.watchPathChange();` into all Template helpers that depend on the params of a route.

So in this case update the sidebar.js -

```
Template.sidebarItem.helpers({
  isSelected() {
    FlowRouter.watchPathChange();
    const slug = FlowRouter.current().params.subSectionSlug;
    if (this.slug === slug) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
});
```

When that helper is used in the sidebarItem template it is now updated whenever the path changes.